# Magento Place Order on Checkout redirects back to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout

We are using Magento Community 1.9.

At checkout, when we click place order using any time of payment options (including zero subtotal checkout where no payment is required), we are redirected back to the shopping cart. The order goes through in the backend and we are also able to see the order success page if we manually type the url /checkout/onepage/success.

At checkout page, we receive a 500 internal error during the saveForm function.

We have already tried many solutions that we have found on other message boards with no success. We also have already increased the php memory limit and execution time.

Our checkout runs on a secure page; when we removed our SSL certificate for testing purposes, placing an order functioned correctly as we expect it to.

Please help us solve this problem.

---

Here is the system.log errors:

```
/var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             </sales_order_save_after> ---!>  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                       ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 123: parser error : Comment not terminated  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 123: parser error : Premature end of data in tag events line 73  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 123: parser error : Premature end of data in tag frontend line 72  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 123: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 28  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 232: parser error : Comment not terminated 
<!-- <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
              in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             </sales_order_item_save_commit_after> --!>  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                   ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 274: parser error : Comment not terminated 
<!-- <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
              in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             <!--- <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():               ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 281: parser error : Comment not terminated 
<!-- <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
              in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             </sales_order_item_save_commit_after> ---!>  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                   ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 398: parser error : Comment not terminated  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 398: parser error : Premature end of data in tag events line 216  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 398: parser error : Premature end of data in tag adminhtml line 190  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 398: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 28  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
2015-01-20T16:29:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592
```

Comment: Please look at `/var/log/exception.log` and `/var/log/system.log` for details on the 500 error, and post the error here.

Comment: have you try any custom extension so please disable and check.

Comment: The exception.log is empty, however, I will post the system.log errors in three messages as it is too long for one

Comment: I had the same problem when setting up mail to send order confirmation emails. I'd edited \local\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php , obviously incorrectly and it caused the same scenario as above. when deleting template.php my billing works again. no idea why... (sorry not enough reputation to comment that but thought it might be useful)

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, it is related to missing php extension on your server. I had similar issue and in my case it was related to missing `php-mbstring` extension on server.

You can debug the error by enabling `display_errors` in your `index.php` file.

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Then on your checkout page, you can check the error output on firebug or similar debugger.

[image: firebug console]

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have a XML syntax error in `/var/www/includes/src/__default.php`. Open the file and see if you have any missing brackets, misspelled nodes, etc.